# Aurelia bundling and exporting not works properly

Tags: aurelia

It is maybe a trivial question but I am quite lost in topic I don't know.

I am writing my first app n Aurelia using ES2016. I wanted to export my app to server for some testing.

As I learn in Plularsight course https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aurelia-fundamentals/ that the easiest way to bundle and export is to use Aurelia Skeleton Navigation  -  by changing all theirs src files to ours and adding all the missing dependencies in package.json, and also adding them to bundle.js and export.js.

When I use

```
git bundle
git serve
```

Bundling works fine, and app is running fine.

But when i run

```
gulp export
```

The files in export dir not working properly. I have an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" error in almost js file I wrote or added to my App (not in aurelia files :/ I deployed it temporally here so you can check https://amazingcms-0-3.firebaseapp.com/drag/posts

It looks like I messed it up at all :/ I don't know what files I should show you to help, so please tell me, or give mi a good source where I can learn how to export my app. It is possible to do it without the Aurelia Skeleton Navigation? I think I even don't necessarily need bundling only transpiling (I'm using Babel runtime). I want to check if my app works on server it can work slow at this step.

Comment: Firstly, I think you should try creating a blank skeleton navigation, run `gulp export` and see what happens. I believe there is an error somewhere in your code, it is very to hard to say something without looking at code. If you upload your code into github I can check for you

Comment: Don't know how firebaseapp.com is working, but posts, config.js, config.css, system.js, custom.css all serve something that looks like your index.html (that doesn't seems to be correct, should serve other content). Is this also this way on your disk?